# How to optimize query to reduce execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My query's order by clause & datetime comparison of between causes the execution time to increase, where as I had indexed the datetime

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    @PeriodStart = DATEADD(SECOND, 1, dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATDateTime) 
FROM         
    dbo.tbl_WPT_EmployeeMachineLink 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tbl_WPT_Machine ON dbo.tbl_WPT_EmployeeMachineLink.FK_tbl_WPT_Machine_ID = dbo.tbl_WPT_Machine.ID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog ON dbo.tbl_WPT_EmployeeMachineLink.FK_tbl_WPT_Machine_ID = dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.FK_tbl_WPT_Machine_ID 
                              AND dbo.tbl_WPT_EmployeeMachineLink.MachineEnrollmentNo = dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATEnrollmentNo
WHERE     
    (dbo.tbl_WPT_EmployeeMachineLink.FK_tbl_WPT_Employee_ID = @EmpID) 
    AND (dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATDateTime BETWEEN @ShiftEndPreviousInstance AND @ShiftStart) 
    AND dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATInOutMode in (1,2,5)
    OR (dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATDateTime BETWEEN @ShiftEndPreviousInstance AND @ShiftStart)
    AND (dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.FK_tbl_WPT_Employee_ID = @EmpID) 
    AND dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATInOutMode in (1,2,5)
ORDER BY
    dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATDateTime DESC
```

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_9.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/refs/rsdperformanceworkspaces.htm) for more details related to sql problem and query related issues click this link https://blog.sqlauthority.com/

Comment: @user12158375 . . . Have you heard of table aliases?  They really make a query easier to write and to read.  Also sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.  Also helping would be an explanation of why the question is tagged with a database that is no longer supported.  You should be using a *supported* version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get an employee's info from multiple sources (`EmployeeMachineLink` and `AttendanceLog`).  Is that correct?  If so, I think you just need to clean up the `WHERE` clause logic:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) 
  @PeriodStart = DATEADD(SECOND, 1, dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATDateTime) 
FROM dbo.tbl_WPT_EmployeeMachineLink eml
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_WPT_Machine ON eml.FK_tbl_WPT_Machine_ID = dbo.tbl_WPT_Machine.ID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog ON eml.FK_tbl_WPT_Machine_ID = dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.FK_tbl_WPT_Machine_ID 
  AND eml.MachineEnrollmentNo = dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATEnrollmentNo
WHERE (
  eml.FK_tbl_WPT_Employee_ID = @EmpID OR
  dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.FK_tbl_WPT_Employee_ID = @EmpID
) 
AND (dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATDateTime BETWEEN @ShiftEndPreviousInstance AND @ShiftStart)
AND dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATInOutMode IN (1,2,5)
ORDER BY dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATDateTime DESC
```

**Changes**
- added table alias `eml` for readability
- removed duplicate reference to `dbo.tbl_WPT_AttendanceLog.ATInOutMode IN (1,2,5)`
- removed duplicate `BETWEEN ... AND ...` reference
- grouped `OR` conditions together

You have to be careful when mixing `OR` with `AND` without using parentheses.  Otherwise that will lead to unexpected results and possibly poor performance.

Let me know if that helps.